# How do I get all combinations of data from a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have spent the last five hours trying to get every product option combination from a table but I'm totally stuck now. I have a table with data like (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE `assigned_options` (
  `option_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
);

INSERT INTO `assigned_options` (`value_id`, `option_id`) VALUES
(4, 2),
(3, 2),
(2, 1),
(1, 1),
(5, 3),
(6, 3),
(7, 3);
```

Say option ID 2 is color with variations red (4) and blue (3), option id 1 size etc....

Is it possible to do this with one MySQL query? I have tried using PHP to make a recurring function to get every possibility but I just can't get it to work.

Any tips GREATLY appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "this" in your statement "Is it possible to do this" ? Your queries except one small mistake in the `CREATE` one are good, and you can build one large long `INSERT` query to add all possible values at one shot. Am I missing something?

Comment: Adding an expected result would help.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to do?  Generate the assigned_options records, get a list of all possible records?  What you're asking for is a little fuzzy...

Comment: @VoidRay +1 must be my alter ego

Answer (score 1):

Given your table... I'm assuming you want every possible combo of value and option.  That's a cross join (a join without any ON or where clause limiting the results):

```
 SELECT a.value_id, b.option_id 
     FROM assigned_options a 
     JOIN assigned_options b 
     GROUP BY a.value_id, b.option_id
```

The group by filters out the duplicate results.

Do you have 2 other tables `value` and `option` that you want to pull all combinations of?

Comment: This doesn't work for mysql - or at least it is veeeeeeeeery slow

Answer (score 1):

```
select option_id, value_id
from assigned_options
group by option_id, value_id
order by option_id, value_id
```

Answer (score 0):

In TSQL you can use a recursive CTE, Can''t remember where I got it, but pretty sweet. Note MYSQL doesn't use "With" option, so it won't work in MySQL

```
WITH Numbers(N) AS (
                    SELECT N
                    FROM ( VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)) Numbers(N)),
                        Recur(N,Combination) AS (
                        SELECT N, CAST(N AS VARCHAR(20)) 
                        FROM Numbers


UNION ALL

SELECT n.N,CAST(r.Combination + ',' + CAST(n.N AS VARCHAR(10)) AS VARCHAR(20)) 
FROM Recur r
INNER JOIN Numbers n ON n.N > r.N)



select Combination
from RECUR
ORDER BY LEN(Combination),Combination;
```